# Подскажите есть ли Open Source для Devops-инженера

Tags: docker, devops, kubernetes, облако, azure-devops

Ищу проект для участия в качестве Devops-инженера, системного администратора.
знаю :

- python
- linux
- bash
- Docker
- устройство сетей, протоколы
- настройка коммутационного оборудования
- и т.п.

Ищу проект в котором работают люди которым интересно то чем они занимаются, также есть огромное желание набраться опыта в качестве Devops.

Подскажите где найти такие проекты и как ?

Comment: Это принципиально не получится, т.к. Devops это по определению уже опытный

Comment: можете более развернуто сказать

Comment: Devops -- это когда разработка кода (или его существенное "допиливание") происходит одновременно с эксплуатацией начального варианта персоналом заказчика. При этом ускоряется реакция на его хотелки. Тут нужны компетентные люди, которые на лету **адекватно** схватывают все новые пожелания заказчика.  Теперь прикиньте, есть ли время (и какая может быть заинтересованность) у руководства этой разработки-внедрения на обучение новичков?